# Blank Page moodle after login CAS

Tags: moodle, cas

i have finished install CAS, PHPCAS, and Wordpress.. i want to install Moodle integration with CAS...
after I installed Moodle and add CAS authentication..
but after I success login CAS.. and move to moodle,

I get blank page, and the url: http://my.address/moodle/login/index.php?authCAS=CAS

i don't know the error, where i can see the moodle error??

any one can help me to resolve it..?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching on Debugging ( https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ).

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? The page I linked to takes you step-by-step through the different ways of turning on debugging within Moodle, in order to get any error messages generated.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when you call /login/index.php

What this does, is starts up all the Moodle libraries. Millions of things happen.

You'll get a white screen when the Login library looks for authentication types. Usually the white screen is because of wrong settings in your authentication. Even for a manual user, these login settings still run.

You must to: /admin/settings.php?section=manageauths

Turn off everything that you can to get this working.

If you cannot log in to the site, you will need to go in to the MySQL database manually (phpmyadmin, sqlyog, etc), and turn off that setting. That will be an adventure...